# Publish a project programmatically C#

Tags: c#, msbuild

I want to be able to publish a separate C# project programmatically. When I run the following code I want it to publish my `Repair.csproj` project.

What I'm doing here is I'm getting the version number from my code. I then increment it by one, delete everything in the publish folder and then try to publish my project.

However when I run this code it doesn't publish my `Repair.csproj`. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

My code is as follows

```
public const string publishLocation = @"C:\Workspace_User\Repair\MAIN\Publish";
public const string RepairLocation = @"C:\Workspace_User\Repair\MAIN\Repair.sln";
public const string repairproj = @"C:\Workspace_User\Repair\MAIN\Repair\Repair.csproj";
public const string r = @"C:\Workspace_User\Repair\MAIN\Repair\bin\Release\Repair.dll";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine.GlobalEngine.BuildEnabled = true;
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(publishLocation);
    FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(RepairLocation);

    var version= AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(r).Version;
    var splitVersionNumber= version.ToString().Split('.');

    var getNumber = splitVersionNumber[3];
    var addInt=Convert.ToInt32(getNumber);
    addInt++;
    foreach  (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
    {
       if (file.Name!="Working Folder")
        {
           file.Delete();
        }    
    }
    buildMethod();
}

public static object buildMethod()
{
    var props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    props["Configuration"] = "Publish";
    var request = new BuildRequestData(repairproj, props, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);
    var parms = new BuildParameters();
    // parms.Loggers = ...;

    var result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(parms, request);
    Debug.Write(result);
    return result.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Success;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using existing tools for this, like [Cake](http://cakebuild.net/)?

Comment: In the future please try to format your code before submitting the question so it is readable, I did it for you this time.

Comment: @mason to be honest I thought it would be pretty easy just to write up a quick console application so it could be run through an .exe.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. That's why tools are there, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. Take a look at these build tools [mentioned on Awesome Dot Net](https://github.com/quozd/awesome-dotnet#build-automation).

Comment: @mason Thanks for your help :)